# How do I fix a Cannot Run error?

Tags: errors, miktex, warnings, winedt

So I am trying to preview my Latex file as a pdf, so when I click pdf preview, an warning pops up stating,

Cannot run:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Maxthon\Bin\Maxthon.exe"`
`"C:\Users\Joe\Documents\Sample(1).pdf".`

So how can I fix this. I have no clue what the `Maxthon.exe` thing is and this is my first time using Latex and Winedt. Also, it will run as a DVI file. Thank you.

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxthon), Maxthon is a Chinese web browser. What happens if you compile your document with `pdflatex` and then try to open the resulting file with Adobe Reader?

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

By default, WinEdt uses the PDF viewer which is associated with `.pdf` files.

Surely you have `.pdf` files associated with Maxthon browser.

I suggest you to install the free [SumatraPDF](http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html) reader which works as a charm together with WinEdt. Install the 64-bit version if you have WinEdt 64-bit, otherwise install the 32-bit version.

If you want to set SumatraPDF as your default PDF reader, remember, during the installation, to click on "Options" and select "Use SumatraPDF as default PDF reader". In this case, restarting WinEdt and clicking on "PDF Preview" your `.pdf` file will be opened with SumatraPDF.

If you don't want either to install SumatraPDF or to set it as your default reader, from within WinEdt, go to to "Options" -> "Execution Modes" -> "PDF Viewer" and browse for the program you want to use as PDF reader:

[image]